# Is there a way to use IF to show NULL values only when no input has been done?

Tags: sql

I need help with a IF-statement or similar

This is to let me make a query report from our system but in some cases EXP_RCPT_NO doesnt have a value and i need a code that let me search for a specific value in EXP_RCPT_NO without showing empty results but at the same time shows the empty results when i search only il.lic_no

```
select il.lic_no,
       EXP_RCPT_NO
   from inv_lic il
 where il.lic_no like nvl ('&Licens', '%')
   and EXP_RCPT_NO like nvl ('&Order', '%')
```

It works if i remove the bottom row, but then it removes the option to search EXP_RCPT_NO

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: Are you sure replacing `AND` with `OR` will not work for your case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select il.lic_no, il.EXP_RCPT_NO
from inv_lic il
where il.lic_no like coalesce('&Licens', '%') and
      (il.EXP_RCPT_NO like '&Order' or '&Order' is null);
```

You may want the `or` logic for both conditions, but you only asked about the second one.

Comment: this definitely works, but im struggling to put it into a bigger code now if you could give me a hand. I'll put the big code in a new answer so it looks decent.

Comment: I got the bigger code to work with using the or logic for all conditions, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Question confusing. It's Oracle right? I'm not completely understanding your question but something like this? The nvl is same as ISNULL is SQL Server. Normally you put this around your column(s).

```
select il.lic_no,
       EXP_RCPT_NO
   from inv_lic il
 where nvl(il.lic_no, 'Licens') like '%Licens%'
   OR nvl(EXP_RCPT_NO, 'Order') like '%Order%'
```